# How can I compute the $n$-th derivative of $e^{a e^{-x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials

I'm trying to compute the $n$-th derivative of the function $e^{a e^{-x}}$, but I'm stuck.

I found that I could use Faa di Bruno's formula but maybe I'm worsening the problem to the computation of the Exponential Bell Polynomial $B_{n, k} (-a e^{-x}, ae^{-x}, -ae^{-x}, ae^{-x}, ...)$ and I'm not sure how to go on. Actually it will be much welcomed even just a way to compute the derivative in the case $x=0$.

Do you think there is a way to compute this derivative in a more or less closed form following this path or another?

Comment: As your function can be seen as the composition of 3 functions, see : https://mathoverflow.net/q/5847/88984 and its answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\partial_x^ne^{ae^{-x}}=\partial_x^ne^{e^{\log a-x}}
$$
Define $t=\log a-x$, then
$$
\partial_x^ne^{e^{\log a-x}}=\partial_{\log a-t}^ne^{e^t}=(-1)^n\partial_t^ne^{e^t}.
$$
Using the Rodrigues formula for the [Touchard polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials)
$$
T_n(e^t)=e^{-e^t} \partial_t^n e^{e^t},
$$
subsequently gives
$$
(-1)^n\partial_t^ne^{e^t}=(-1)^ne^{e^t}T_n(e^t)=(-1)^ne^{e^{\log a-x}}T_n(e^{\log a-x})=(-1)^ne^{ae^{-x}}T_n(ae^{-x}).
$$
With the explicit expression for the Touchard polynomials we conclude
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{%
\partial_x^ne^{ae^{-x}}=(-1)^ne^{ae^{-x}}\sum_{k=0}^n\left\{{n\atop k}\right\}a^ke^{-kx},%
}
$$
where $\{{n\atop k}\}$ are the Stirling numbers of the 2nd-kind.

Evaluating at $x=0$ gives
$$
\partial_x^ne^{ae^{-x}}\bigg|_{x=0}=(-1)^ne^a\sum_{k=0}^n\left\{{n\atop k}\right\}a^k=(-1)^ne^a\mathsf E(X^n),
$$
where $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(a)$.

Answer (score 5):

$\def\B{\operatorname B}$
Series expansion:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{a e^{-x}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a^k}{k!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-kx}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a^k(-k)^ne^{-kx}}{k!} $$

Remember the [Bell polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html)

$$e^x\B_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^n x^k}{k!}$$

therefore:

$$\boxed{\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{ae^{-x}}=(-1)^n e^{ae^{-x}}\B_n(a e^{-x})}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Be%5E%28catalan+e%5E-x%29%2C%7Bx%2C5%7D%5D%3D%28-1%29%5E5+e%5E%28+catalan+e%5E%28-x%29%29BellB%285%2Ccatalan+e%5E-x%29). Alternatively, use the Bell polynomial recurrence relation:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{ae^{-x}}=(-1)^n e^{ae^{-x}}f_n(a e^{-x}),f_n(y)=y\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}kf_k(y)$$

Comment: Nice and concise (+1)

Answer (score 0):

If you differentiate it once, you get

\begin{equation}
-ae^{-x} e^{ae^{-x}}
\end{equation}

This is the product of two functions you know how to differentiate (the first one being $e^{-x}$, the second one being $e^{ae^{-x}}$, that we just differentiated).

It looks like it could be a good case for an induction + the general Leibniz formula for derivatives:

\begin{equation}
(fg)^{(n)} = \displaystyle\sum_{k \leq n} \binom{n}{k} f^{(n-k)} g^{(k)}
\end{equation}

where the $^{(k)}$ exponent denotes the $k$-th derivative.